# Google Signing Token - Invalid Request Signature (Postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-storage

When trying to create a valid signature for google cloud storage I always get:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.

I am able to verify that the canonical request hash matches the 
`StringToSign`'s canonical request hash.

So I believe there is a bug when generating the signature. But all seems to correct (at least from what google docs are telling me)

```
create or replace function qx.create_google_storage_signature(
  string_to_sign text,
  request_date text,
  request_location text,
  request_service text,
  request_type text
)
  returns text
  volatile
  language plpgsql
as $$
declare
  hmac_secret text;
  key_date text;
  key_region text;
  key_service text;
  signing_key text;
  message_digest text;
begin
  -- todo : we need to not store this in plain text
  hmac_secret = qx.current_setting('qx.google_storage_hmac_secret');

  -- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures#derive-key
  key_date = hmac(request_date, concat('GOOG4', hmac_secret), 'sha256');
  key_region = hmac(request_location, key_date, 'sha256');
  key_service = hmac(request_service, key_region, 'sha256');
  signing_key = hmac(request_type, key_service, 'sha256');

  message_digest = hmac(string_to_sign, signing_key, 'sha256');

  -- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures#after_signing
  return encode(message_digest::text::bytea, 'hex');
end
$$;
```

Here is the full sql code:
https://gist.github.com/lukepolo/1bc4ee9e8133ab33484a8d8ec8ef9e17

Comment: Which language are you using? and you mentioned to be following a Google Documentation which one are you following?  Also [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/managing-hmackeys#storage-create-hmac-key-php) there are a few examples on how to use  HMAC keys with cloud Storage. Also could you share the error message you are getting

Comment: I am using Postgresql, I am manually trying to sign following : https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually.

The error message is in the original post  "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I messed up the types should have been bytea

```
create or replace function qx.create_google_storage_signature(
  string_to_sign text,
  request_date text,
  request_location text,
  request_service text,
  request_type text
)
  returns text
  volatile
  language plpgsql
as $$
declare
  hmac_secret text;
  message_digest text;
begin
  -- todo : we need to not store this in plain text
  hmac_secret = qx.current_setting('qx.google_storage_hmac_secret');

  -- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures#derive-key
  message_digest = hmac(string_to_sign::text::bytea, hmac(request_type::text::bytea, hmac(request_service::text::bytea, hmac(request_location::text::bytea, hmac(request_date, concat('GOOG4', hmac_secret), 'sha256'), 'sha256'), 'sha256'), 'sha256'), 'sha256');

  -- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures#after_signing
  return encode(message_digest::text::bytea, 'hex');
end
$$;
```